# Rails: Make model to read and edit only own data by CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I have `Admin` and `Partner` models. `Partner` has_many `Services`. I am using Devise and CanCanCan. I have set my defaults in my `application_controller`:

```
# This is for changing defaults for CanCanCan
 def current_ability
   if admin_signed_in?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin)
   elsif partner_signed_in?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_partner)
 end
end
```

Now inside my `Abilities` class:

```
case model
  # if model is Admin
  when Admin
    can :manage, :all

  # if model is Partner
  when Partner
    can :read, Partner, id: model.id

    can :manage, Service, partner_id: model.id, partner: {active: true}
    can :create, Service

    can :update, Partner, id: model.id, active: true


  else
    cannot :read, :all
end
```

`model` is an parameter i made instead of old `user`. I have placed a lot of `if can?` conditions inside my views.

**Now here is the question**: depending on who logged in, how I can restrict access to `pages and controllers` combining `Devise` and `CanCanCan`?

I thought I will add somethinglike this for every controller:

```
before_action :check_logged_in

def check_logged_in
    if partner_signed_in?
       # do something
    elsif admin_signed_in?
       # do something
    end
end
```

But this makes `CanCanCan` useless and will be hard to maintain if I have too many controllers.

I thought I should use `load_and_authorize_resource` for my controllers, but I have only `Admin` and `Partner` models that has Devise authorization and there are a lot of controllers of models that does not need any authorization or even without models.

Comment: by pages we mean services ? or is there other models too ?

Comment: Yes, partners has many services and can create them. I think there will be more models in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know how to do it on all models, but you can make rules on each model like this

```
when Partner
  can :manage, Service, user_id: user.id
```

This will only allow the partner to manage services `where(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Isn't `can :manage, Service, partner_id: model.id` is more correct? Also how I will restrict access to pages where `partner` is not supposed to be?

Comment: the first `user_id` refers to the field in the service model, which might be as you said `partner_id`, the second `user` is the current user that is supposed to be initialized in the beginning of the ability file

Comment: If I do not mention some actions, it will be considered as `cannot`?

Comment: every thing by default is a `cannot`, you just white list by `can`, the reason of the existence of `cannot` is that you can `can` a huge set and `cannot` a subset of them, for example `can :manage` then add `cannot :destroy`

Comment: How I can restrict access to some pages?

Comment: how do you determine which will you restrict? for example i could add a restricted boolean and add the condition to cancan telling it to only allow `restricted: false`

Comment: I thought restrict by model type. If in current page `Admin` allow something like that.

Comment: you could use `user.class == Partner` or `user.class == Admin`, if both partner and admin are subclasses of `User`